# Turbo Rails back button does not trigger page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I have a turbo frame with a `src` attribute, this works as expected when I load the page, but if I visit another page and click the back button it doesn't work. The `src` url is not been triggered.

```
= turbo_frame_tag "#{dom_id(object)}_active_tab" do
  = turbo_frame_tag "documents", src: documents_path(object_id: object, format: :html)
```